# linux maven vs mac maven

Tags: linux, macos, maven, operating-system

we are working in a multi-module maven project in both Linux machine and Mac machine with the same pom.xml, and we run the below command in offline mode

> mvn install antrun:run -o

The problem is maven downloads a different version of plugins for the same pom.xml file. The difference is listed here [comparison of Mac and Linux machine plugin jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLmWU.png)

We did not specify the version of plugins in pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Test</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>test.mac_linux</groupId>
                            <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <file>${home_dir}/Downloads/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar</file>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <target>
                        <zip destfile="${home_dir}/linux_mac_testing_maven/Testing_mac.zip">
                            <fileset dir="${home_dir}/.m2/repository/" includes="**/*" />
                        </zip>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources-WEB_INF</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${home_dir}/linux_mac_testing_maven/Resources/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${home_dir}/CustomReport_files/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**.*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

does anybody know why maven differs its characteristics when subjected to a different operating system?

Comment: Remove the configuration for maven-install-plugin cause the given jar file is available from maven central this can simply be achieved by defining it as a dependency...Remove the usage of maven-antrun-plugin cause creating a zip archive can be done with maven-assembly-plugin.. Furthermore the configuration wth maven-resources-plugin does not make sense cause if this is a WAR project you should use packaging war instead etc....Apart from that what kind of differences do you really have between mac and linux both are linux based and you are using Java there shouldn't be an issue.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You mention in https://jira.apache.org/jira/projects/MNG/issues/MNG-6470 you are using different versions of Maven (3.5 on Mac and 3.3.9 on Linux). Please update both to latest (3.5.4) and then compare results.